# R script doesn't run from crontab after a while

Tags: r, cron, rscript

I've been troubleshooting this for sometime now. I'm getting some quite unexpected behaviour. I've place a job in /etc/crontab to be run bihourly. It's an R script that produces a png graphic displayed on my server's webpage. It's called in the form:

0,30 * * * * my_user Rscript /path/to/file

What's odd is that it works for an hour or so before the graphic stops updating. If I ssh into the machine and then edit /etc/crontab without even changing anything, it'll start running again. Anyone know what might cause such an issue?

EDIT: I messed around with it a bit more, and it's getting even weirder. I'm running a PHP file from cron that scrapes some text and writes it to file. The PHP continues to work even when R has ceased to run.

Comment: General tip, always use absolute paths in cronjobs.

Comment: You should be able to run your own experiments to try and figure out what's wrong. To rule out something wrong with your R script, can you run it manually four times in a row and get the expected output? To rule out the crontab, can you schedule a job like `0,30 * * * * date >> /path/to/log/file` and get the expected output? Based on the results of these tests, design more tests to take you each time closer to the root problem.

Comment: Have you checked your log files? Probably `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to run once every two hours, you will have to use the slash, "/", character in your field. The slash character is the "step" character. In the case of a two hourly schedule, your time component of your cron file will read:

```
0 */2 * * *
```

The second field, "*/2", means every alternate hour.

Similarly, if you want something to run every 3 hours, you can change that field to "*/3", and so on.

[bihourly: Occurring once every two hours.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bihourly)